# Error trying to stub a map

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I've a method that I'm trying to unit test using mocks. Here is the method:

```
  {...
        mapMasterMap = this.sysAdminService.getMasterData();

        final Map<String, MasterVO> codeMap = (Map<String, MasterVO>) mapMasterMap
                .get("mvo");
        final Map<String, String> sessionMap = (Map<String, String>) mapMasterMap
                .get("smap");
        dataVO.setSessionMap(sessionMap);
        dataVO.setVO1(codeMap.get("vo1"));
        dataVO.setVO2(codeMap.get("vo2"));
        sCommand.setDataVO(dataVO);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
         return mav;
    }
    return mav;
}
```

And what I am trying to do is stub the 1st line so that mapMasterMap contains a valid map (and the codeMap.gets don't blow up) - like:

```
{
    @Mock
    private MasterVO masterVO;
        @Mock
    private SysAdminService sysAdminService;


    @InjectMocks
    private SysAdminController sysAdminController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
                when(this.sysAdminService.getMasterData())
                .thenReturn(new HashMap<String, MasterVO>() {{
                    this.put("mvo",this.masterVO);
                }};
    }

    @Test
    public final void testType(){}
```

I'm getting an error:

> The method `thenReturn(Map<String,Object>)` in the type
>   `OngoingStubbing<Map<String,Object>>` is not applicable for the
>   arguments (`new HashMap<String,MasterVO>(){}`)

So, firstly - am I following the right approach?
If yes, how can I fix this?

Comment: First off, don't use [the double-brace pattern](https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/08/dont-be-clever-the-double-curly-braces-anti-pattern/) - it's a source of memory leaks among other issues. [Guava's `ImmutableMap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained) has a fluent builder pattern if you want to construct a `Map` inline.

Comment: Also why did you only include part of your method? What is the method signature? What type is `mav`? What is `blah;`? If you're having compilation issues, sharing the real code you're trying to compile is a necessary first step for getting useful guidance.

Comment: mav is ModelAndView - I removed rest because those seemed irrelevant to the question.

Comment: You're getting an error related to incorrect method signatures and types, but aren't including the relevant methods. Perhaps `mav` isn't relevant, but it's hard to discern that when you don't include actually relevant details such as the signature of `getMasterData()`. Especially for compilation problems you should always be able to [create an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that *we can run* which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The message says it all: You can't `thenReturn` a `HashMap<String, MasterVO>` where Java asks for a `Map<String,Object>`, which Mockito derives from the return type of `getMasterData`. You'll have to pass in a `HashMap<String, Object>` or any other `Map<String, Object>`, which in your case is as easy as changing the type in your stubbing call.

```
when(this.sysAdminService.getMasterData())
    .thenReturn(new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        this.put("mvo",this.masterVO);
    }});
```

*Why?* In Java, [generics are not covariant](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp01255/): Even though MasterVO necessarily extends Object, you can't use one in place of the other. Otherwise you could easily do this:

```
Map<String, MasterVO> stubMap = new HashMap<String, MasterVO>();
when(this.sysAdminService.getMasterData()).thenReturn(stubMap);
Map<String, Object> returnedMap = this.sysAdminService.getMasterData();

// now returnedMap == stubMap, except you've lost some safety
returnedMap.put("and this is why", "generic types are not covariant");  // legal
MasterVO exceptItIsnt = stubMap.get("and this is why");  // ClassCastException!
```

**Note:** As dimo414 mentioned, don't use double brace syntax. It creates an unnecessary Java class and can leak memory.

Comment: thanks - so now when I try - 'when(this.sysAdminService.getPaymentMasterData()) .thenReturn(ImmutableMap.of("mvo", (Object) this.masterVO));' I still get a ClassCastException on: 'final Map<String, MasterVO> codeMap = (Map<String, MasterVO>) mapMasterMap .get("mvo");' – user2666282 6 mins ago